# Office.context.ui undefiend for Outlook Web App with Exchange 2013 account

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-web-addins, outlook-web-app, exchange-server-2013

I need outlook web add-in supported for Exchange 2013 accounts. So after adding manifest file for Outlook web app The add-in is loading nicely.

I am using Dialog API popup for **Sign In** functionality. So when customer is clicking on sign in  button it shows `Cannot read property 'displayDialogAsync' of undefined`

while debugging I came to know that **Office.context** does not contain **ui** property.

Can anyone guide where I am going wrong ? Or Is this Dialog API supported for Outlook web app containing exchange accounts.

> My add-in is working nicely for Outlook Desktop, Outlook Web and
>   mobile as well

```
if (window.hasOwnProperty('Office')) {
      Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(
        `${window.location.origin}/#/signin/` + Office.context.mailbox.userProfile.emailAddress,
        {
          height: 60,
          width: 20
        },
        (result) => {
          const dialog = result.value;
          dialog.addEventHandler(
            Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived,
            (e: { type: string, message: string }) => {
              if (e.message === 'true') {
                this.oAuthService.initImplicitFlow();
              }
              dialog.close();
            });
        }
      );
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You need to check the requirements set.

Requirement sets are named groups of API members. Office Add-ins use requirement sets specified in the manifest or uses a runtime check to determine whether an Office host supports APIs that an add-in needs. For more information, see Office versions and requirement sets. The [displayDialogAsync](http://displayDialogAsync) method is available in the `DialogApi` requirement set for Word, Excel, or PowerPoint add-ins, and in the Mailbox requirement set 1.4 for Outlook.

See [Dialog API requirement sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/dialog-api-requirement-sets) for more information about requirements for the **Dialog API**.

### Error handling

Your callback needs to check `result.error.code` and `result.error.message`. Once you know what the error is, you can start troubleshooting. For example.

```
var dialog;
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync('https://myDomain/myDialog.html',
   function (asyncResult) {
       if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
            showNotification(asyncResult.error.code = ": " + asyncResult.error.message);
       } else {
            dialog = asyncResult.value;
            dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, processMessage);
      }
});
```

Comment: I checked using code : Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported("DialogApi",1.1). It is not supported So What can be the alternative for this ?

Comment: Try checking `Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported("DialogApi",1.4)` .

Comment: DialogApi is only available with version 1.1, So why to try with 1.4 ? well, It returned false for exchange 2013 account

Comment: DialogAPI 1.1 is only available on Mailbox Api Requirment Set 1.4. For Exchange 2013 On Prem, 1.4 is not supported, so you will not be able to use the dialog api. You will have to do whatever code it is you want, inside the main taskpane if possible.