# Authentication in Office Add-ins when Dialog API is not supported

Tags: iframe, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins, outlook-web-app

Can anyone help to understand how can I implement alternative of Office Dialog API

- I am trying to implement web add-in support for Exchange 2013
  accounts in Outlook web app(Outlook web Access).
- Our add-in is working completely fine with Office 365, Outlook
  Desktop and Mobile as well.
- As per my research Dialog API is not supported for my requirement, So
  I have to go for some classic popup mechanism.
- We have Angular 6 SPA that redirects to Identity Server for
  authentication.
- So I am trying to implement the same for my case But after clicking on Signin, popup is opened but redirection to identity server is being blocked.

**Update :**

- As per the documentation Dialog API is supported for Mailbox > 1.3.
  But as I am using exchange 2013 accounts in Outlook web App(Outlook web Access) for that Mailbox
  version is 1.1.

  **Ref:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.ui?view=office-js
- I tried `Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported("DialogApi",1.1)`
  to check If It is supported or not.It returned false.
- **Reference for code:** [Office.context.ui undefiend for Outlook Web App with Exchange 2013 account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57050992/office-context-ui-undefiend-for-outlook-web-app-with-exchange-2013-account)

So How can I eliminate or Is there any alternative of this ?

Comment: Can you please clarify why Dialog API cannot be used for your case? Which platform you are trying this on: Outlook Win32 or Outlook-Web-App? If you could share your code-snippet to understand what you are trying will help us understand the scenario better.

Comment: I have updated my question to make it more clear

Comment: We do not have any other suggestion apart from Dialog API which is not supported in your required environment.

Comment: What is your views on classic pop-ups ? will it work ? currently It's blocking redirection to identity server. Can this be eliminated ?

Comment: If there is an issue with the pop-up, did you add the domain names as 'AppDomain' entries to the XML manifest for the app?

Comment: I have added already, But the problem currently is The popup is not redirecting to the route specified instead It redirect to index.html